# When should a method depend on a data source and NOT have it declared as a parameter?

Tags: programming-practices, solid, patterns-and-practices, readability, maintainability

I was assigned a code review to one of my colleagues.
I posed the following, which I wanted to share here in order to hear whether I am right or wrong.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public void DoSomethingWithList()
{
   var list = AnotherClass.GetList();
   var itemsToRemove = list.Where(...);
   list.Remove(itemsToRemove);
   .
   .
   .
}
```

I argue that the method above should have `list` declared as a dependency (in other words, declared as a parameter in the method's signature). Why ? To follow the [Single Responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), and/or for testing purposes. (I think this is the case for an external class call, but even if `GetList` was a private method inside the same class, I would still claim the same - even if the sole motif would be code clarity (call it "*purpose clarity*").

My colleague says this is not so. Having to call this function every time always passing the same parameter is cumbersome.

I obviously understand that as a developer, but I insisted that the "*software engineering principles aimed at code maintainability*" should prevail over "*developer laziness*" (myself included !)

I do understand there are no bulletproof rules, but nevertheless that they
should only be broken for a very good reason.

I wonder whether I am wrong. And if am I not, which other aspects I did not mention should have been.

Comment: Is `AnotherClass.GetList()` a static method?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the single responsibility principle.

Comment: "Having to call this function every time always passing the same parameter is cumbersome." - that is why we have these things called objects that can be parameterized by a dependency (constructor injection) and then passed around as a small bundle of pre-configured functions. :D --- P.S. In functional languages a similar idea appears in the form of higher-order functions and partial application; these are, in some sense, similar to constructors that produce single-method objects.

Comment: @JacquesB: for the sake of achieving the purpose we all ended up reaching each other here - i.e., provide helpful insights into a problem - I would rather leave constructive remarks. Some 5 users left useful bits in this way or another, while you preferred to be singled out by not being one of those. I suppose you would opt to tell your child "Nope, this is not an ant, it's a spider, look, it has 4 legs on each side instead of 3!" instead of "No. This is not a spider, period. (and this is all my knowledge can help with)"

Comment: An appropriate and *constructive* response to JacquesB would be to, either 1: Say why this does relate to SRP, or 2: Agree that it doesn't and edit the question to remove that distraction. or 3: Ignore him and keep refining your question. Refining and focusing the question is a constructive form of input here. It makes the question more useful to future readers. We're not here just to 'get our questions answered'. We're here to build a good library of q&a that is useful for everyone to search. That means we need to refine questions and answers.

Comment: @joshp - well maybe Veverke didn't want to repay an unhelpful comment with a constructive response; while JacquesB's comment may have been well-intentioned, it lacks enough context for the OP to either write a rebuttal or to agree with it, and it does not provide guidance as to how to refine the question. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with pointing that out, as long as the exchange doesn't turn into a highly charged back-and-forth spiraling out of control. I'll grant you that Veverke's response was perhaps a bit disproportionate, but we're not at the "spiraling out of control" point yet.

Comment: @joshp Well, how granular you want to go with SRP depends on which aspects of your code are likely to change, but here, because the function is calling a global internally to obtain the list, the function knows where the list is coming from and how to obtain it (so that's one responsibility), in addition to doing it's primary task (another responsibility). So, if the source of the list is expected to change (due to requirements, or due to reuse in different contexts, or because of testing), the function would have to be needlessly modified; it's also likely not cohesive - the flip side of SRP.

Comment: @joshp On the other hand, if this expectation of change or reuse is not warranted (not reasonable to expect such changes, or no previous history of such changes, or no actual reuse within the codebase), then this particular SRP/cohesion violation is hypothetical and may not be worth pursuing.

Comment: Does "has nothing to do with Single Responsibility" mean that I should have mentioned the Decoupling principle instead ? Don't they overlap a little bit somewhere, in that SR is always broken when you couple additional responsibilities into yours ?

Comment: @Veverke: Sorry for the pithy comment you called me out for. Just wanted to point out SRP is the wrong lens to look at this. But there are already many other questions about what SRP is and isn't on this site, so an explanation would just duplicate things already said. But in short, SRP is about potential change requests at the requirements/stakeholder level, not about implementation details.

Comment: @JacquesB: it's ok, I do understand the point, as I did before... All is good. Sorry if I looked reluctant in accept I lack in understanding here. It just happens too often :-)

Comment: Have you answered the question that @JohnWu asked? The method to retrieve the list being static can actually make a big difference here.

Comment: @JohnWu: yes it is

Comment: I did not immediately relate neither to JohnWu and others technical details inquiries because originally I really came with a much *primitive* point of view in which, like the lines Filip Milovanovic writes, simply deals with the question of *why mix responsibilities*. **Foo** is responsible for doing something with the data, and fetching the data is a different responsibility. From here, all the testability stuff (which most certainly is correct) derives from. In my very humble understanding.

Answer (score 7):

Between being right and wrong, there is a third possibility, that you're both right.

You are correct at one level, and your colleague is correct that we should bundle things together so that we don't have to deal with two variables when one would do.

Sometimes when there is this kind of tension there is a missing abstraction or entity.

I'd suggest to do it your way with parameter — and also provide another entity for your colleagues to use in their parameterless way.  This other entity will bind, in construction, to what was otherwise the parameter (e.g. the list).  It is a new entity that represents the binding of the two items, so that callers have only one item to deal with instead of dealing with a pair of items that are conceptually (but only implicitly and informally) bundled.

Answer (score 1):

This method is somewhat difficult to test because it doesn't take anything in nor does it return anything back.  So, to test you would need to know something about the internals of the method, that is what is being modified internally.

Testing it involves calling that method and inspecting the results of the AnotherClasses.GetList() method.  It also might involve some setup to initially create the list so you can see the results of DoSomethingWithList().

That's not ideal but doable.

Passing in the list makes the function more explicit.

```
DoSomethingWithList(List theList)
```

If I casually look at that I can assume the list may be modified in some way.  Straight forward to write a test.

DoSomethingWithList() does not have that clarity.

As Erik suggests, try it both ways, and find out which is easier to read, understand, and test.  At the end of the day, that it what matters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on DDD pricinpal, I think the answer depends on is it a Domain Service method or an Application layer method.

1. If this is a Domain Service method, I think you are right. The original design violate the Single Responsibility principal. The main issue here is this code is not test friendly, the reponsiblity of retrieving the list leaked into your domain service logic. It makes the unit test impossible without introducing some kind of mocking framework (e.g. Mockito). And it makes the integration test even harder.

   Think about the case that your domain service actually works perfectly but the `AnotherClass.GetList()` has some bug won't return the right list. Then if the code failed, you are the first person got called to blame and you are the one forced to investigate the bug.

   But if we refactor the code to:

   ```
   public void DoSomethingWithList(List<T> theList) {
       if(!isValid(theList)) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("The list is not valid for processing");
       }
       // Normal logic below
       ... ...
   }
   ```

   We can obtain the benefits:

   - We can create comprehensive Test cases to cover as many scanarios as possbile.
   - We can create test cases to iterate illegal argument problems at development and compile time.
   - We can create bean validator to guard against the input argument at runtime without letting garbage input directly penerate into our domain logic.
   - We can use the specific runtime exception to let's know where the exact problem is. Is it an argument issue or is it the domain logic issue? A clear answer helps us to reduce the maintenance cost.
2. If it is application layer code, you may not have to enforce the design principals. But based the developer's argument, this logic is reused in different places, it is obviously not a good design to put it in application layer and the better option is to extract the domain logic from the application layer to make it a Domain Service which will make your whole application more testable, flexible and robust.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your friend's approach is that it is impossible to stub out the call to `GetList()` for unit testing, since it is a static method. You will be unable to test `DoSomethingWithList` without also testing `GetList`. This could be a serious problem for your automated tests if the backing store for `GetList` is not available on the test bed environment.

The easy path forward is to convert `AnotherClass` to an instanced class and inject it. You then register it with your IoC container as a singleton so everyone shares the same copy.

```
interface IAnotherClass 
{
    List<Foo> GetList();
}

class AnotherClass : IAnotherClass
{
    private IExpensiveDatabaseConnection _singleInstance; 

    public List<Foo> GetList()
    {
        return _singleInstance.GetList();
    }
}



class Bar
{
    protected readonly IAnotherClass _anotherClass;

    public Bar(IAnotherClass anotherClass)
    {
        _anotherClass = anotherClass;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithList()
    {
        var list = _anotherClass.GetList();
        var itemsToRemove = list.Where(...);
        list.Remove(itemsToRemove);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're going to do this, you may need to refactor other code to match it. If this is a legacy code base with a lot of static method calls, it might be more cost effective to continue using the old pattern.